# i have been trying to separate the column of my csv file. actually there are 6 column but some column are 5 and it affecting my result

Tags: python, csv, jupyter-notebook

2018-03-06 12:23:13;read;country_5;2458291108;Australia
2018-03-06 12:23:16;read;country_7;2458291957;Reddit;Australia
2018-03-06 12:23:19;read;country_7;2458203986;Asia
2018-03-06 12:23:25;read;country_6;2458291958;Reddit;Asia
2018-03-06 12:23:25;read;country_7;2458286097;Asia
2018-03-06 12:23:31;read;country_5;2458291846;Australia
2018-03-06 12:23:33;read;country_5;2458291959;Reddit;Asia
2018-03-06 12:23:38;read;country_4;2458291960;AdWords;Asia
2018-03-06 12:23:42;read;country_2;2458199318;Europe

Answer (score 0):

If the above is the content of your file then you can use the basic operation of python.

```
column1 = []
column2 = []
column3 = []
column4 = []
column5 = []
fopen = open("filename.csv","r")
lines  = fopen.readlines()
for line in lines:
   fields = line.split(";")
   field[0].append(column1)
   field[2].append(column2)
   .....#put for other columns as well
```

Now you got five lists you can convert this into series and you can make dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your input file looks like

```
2018-03-06 12:23:13;read;country_5;2458291108;Australia
2018-03-06 12:23:16;read;country_7;2458291957;Reddit;Australia
2018-03-06 12:23:19;read;country_7;2458203986;Asia
2018-03-06 12:23:25;read;country_6;2458291958;Reddit;Asia
2018-03-06 12:23:25;read;country_7;2458286097;Asia
2018-03-06 12:23:31;read;country_5;2458291846;Australia
2018-03-06 12:23:33;read;country_5;2458291959;Reddit;Asia 
2018-03-06 12:23:38;read;country_4;2458291960;AdWords;Asia
2018-03-06 12:23:42;read;country_2;2458199318;Europe
```

and the problem is the last two columns.

If you do this (file named `input.csv` here)

```
import csv

lines = []
with open('input.csv', 'r') as file:
    csv_file = csv.reader(file, delimiter=';')
    for line in csv_file:
        if len(line) == 5: # If input for column 5 is missing: insert placeholder
            line = line[:4] + ['NO INPUT', line[4]]
        lines.append(line)
```

or shorter

```
with open('input.csv', 'r') as file:
    lines = [line[:4] + ['NO INPUT', line[4]] if len(line) == 5 else line
             for line in csv.reader(file, delimiter=';')]
```

you get the following *aligned* `lines`

```
[
 ['2018-03-06 12:23:13', 'read', 'country_5', '2458291108', 'NO INPUT', 'Australia'],
 ['2018-03-06 12:23:16', 'read', 'country_7', '2458291957', 'Reddit', 'Australia'],
 ['2018-03-06 12:23:19', 'read', 'country_7', '2458203986', 'NO INPUT', 'Asia'],
 ['2018-03-06 12:23:25', 'read', 'country_6', '2458291958', 'Reddit', 'Asia'],
 ['2018-03-06 12:23:25', 'read', 'country_7', '2458286097', 'NO INPUT', 'Asia'],
 ['2018-03-06 12:23:31', 'read', 'country_5', '2458291846', 'NO INPUT', 'Australia'],
 ['2018-03-06 12:23:33', 'read', 'country_5', '2458291959', 'Reddit', 'Asia '],
 ['2018-03-06 12:23:38', 'read', 'country_4', '2458291960', 'AdWords', 'Asia'],
 ['2018-03-06 12:23:42', 'read', 'country_2', '2458199318', 'NO INPUT', 'Europe']
]
```

I have filled in the missing 5th columns with `'NO INPUT'`. You can of course do here whatever seems appropriate (for example `None`).

If you actually want to separete the columns: This

```
columns = [[] for _ in range(6)]
with open('input.csv', 'r') as file:
    csv_file = csv.reader(file, delimiter=';')
    for line in csv_file:
        if len(line) == 5: # If input for column 5 is missing: insert placeholder
            line = line[:4] + ['NO INPUT', line[4]]
        for i, item in enumerate(line):
            columns[i].append(item)
```

or a bit more compact

```
with open('input.csv', 'r') as file:
    lines = [line[:4] + ['NO INPUT', line[4]] if len(line) == 5 else line
             for line in csv.reader(file, delimiter=';')]
columns = [[lines[i][j] for i in range(len(lines))] for j in range(6)]
```

gives you

```
[
 ['2018-03-06 12:23:13', '2018-03-06 12:23:16', '2018-03-06 12:23:19', '2018-03-06 12:23:25', '2018-03-06 12:23:25', '2018-03-06 12:23:31', '2018-03-06 12:23:33', '2018-03-06 12:23:38', '2018-03-06 12:23:42'],
 ['read', 'read', 'read', 'read', 'read', 'read', 'read', 'read', 'read'],
 ['country_5', 'country_7', 'country_7', 'country_6', 'country_7', 'country_5', 'country_5', 'country_4', 'country_2'],
 ['2458291108', '2458291957', '2458203986', '2458291958', '2458286097', '2458291846', '2458291959', '2458291960', '2458199318'],
 ['NO INPUT', 'Reddit', 'NO INPUT', 'Reddit', 'NO INPUT', 'NO INPUT', 'Reddit', 'AdWords', 'NO INPUT'],
 ['Australia', 'Australia', 'Asia', 'Asia', 'Asia', 'Australia', 'Asia ', 'Asia', 'Europe']
]
```